# what is the equivalent of batch execute/find in powershell

Tags: batch-file, powershell

In batch script i can do the following ...

```
execute command | findstr.exe "string_to_look"
```

if it's not there then i have %errorlevel% different than 0

In Powershell, seems that select-string does not have the same behavior.

Comment: I still use `findstr` for this purpose when using powershell. Echo `$?` after your command and you will get True/False dependent on the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the output on a condition and use an `if` statement to test whether there were any matches:

```
PS C:\> dir test*


    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
-a---        23/12/2013     16:12      19820 test.html

PS C:\> if (dir | ? { $_ -match 'test' }) { echo 'yes' }
yes
PS C:\> if (dir | ? { $_ -match 'testx' }) { echo 'yes' }
PS C:\>
```

Be aware though that if the command is a Powershell cmdlet then you need to test the specific properties as the lines you see displayed aren't what goes into the test:

```
PS C:\> if (dir | ? { $_.Length -eq 19820 }) { echo 'yes' }
yes
```

For my example command just testing `$_` tests on the name only.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
if (someCommand | Select-String "string_to_look")
{
   # found!
}
```

Or like this:

```
$found = someCommand | Select-String "string_to_look"
if ($found)
{
   # found!
}
```

The reason it works is that `Select-String` returns `$null` if it doesn't find anything, which evaluates to `$false`, and it returns a `MatchInfo` (or an array of `MatchInfo`) if it does find something, which evaluates to `true`.

Comment: This is the approach I would take.

Comment: But if the *someCommand* is something like "dir" then this won't work because the objects passed to Select-String are DirectoryInfo objects, not strings.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to just know whether the string is there or not you could do something like this (using `dir` as an example):

```
$doesItHaveStringICareAbout = (dir | Out-String).Contains("string_to_look")
```

Answer (score 1):

`findstr` does still work in PowerShell, since it's an external command. However, it's not very PoSh, so I wouldn't recommend using it.

You can use the `Where-Object` cmdlet (or its alias `?`) with the various [comparison operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx). The `-like` operator is the one most similar to the default behavior of `findstr`, except that you need to add wildcards at beginning and/or end of the search string when you're looking for partial matches:

```
if (& command | ? { $_ -like '*string_to_look*' }) {
  ...
}
```

The `-match` operator matches the input against a regular expression (like `findstr /r`):

```
if (& command | ? { $_ -match 'regexp_to_look' }) {
  ...
}
```

You could also use `Select-String` cmdlet, which will use regular expressions by default, but can be instructed to use simple matching with a parameter:

```
if (& command | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'string_to_look') {
  ...
}
```

If `Where-Object` or `Select-String` don't find a match, the result of the pipeline is `$null`, which [evaluates to `$false`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx). Otherwise the result is a non-empty array, which evaluates to `$true`.